# how to auto increment character primary key in postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Currently, the primary key looks like `a06E0000007q66cIAA`. I want to auto increment this key, so next time when i create a record it will be unique and auto-incremented.

Any idea how to ?

Rightnow, i am doing something like this

```
begin 
 m = Model1.new
 m.id = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)[0..10]
 m.foo = 'bar'
 m.save
rescue 
  retry 
end
```

I am using `retry` method because if the exception raised because of NonUnique `id`, the above method will try again and this will hopefully generate `Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand].join)` unique key .

This is the worse thing i am doing,i want to eliminate this.

Extra information:

I am using postgresql and Rails 4.

```
 ➜  ~  postgres --version
 postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.2
```

datatype of `id` which is primary key.

```
 "id" character varying(255) NOT NULL
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using `uuid` keys instead, if you must do this. Even with the birthday paradox in play, your collision chance is so low as to be negligible.

Comment: Check the lengths of the current keys (all equal? or what are the min and max lengths?) and what's their alphabet. If there are 255 chars available for the width, the unicity and incrementing look like an easy problem to solve.